# Create nullable checker in recoil refine without undefined in return type

Tags: reactjs, types, react-state-management, recoiljs

I am encountering the following error message when trying to use the nullable checker from the library `@recoiljs/refine` with an atom: "`Type 'AtomEffect<Zone | null | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'AtomEffect<Zone | null>'.`"

Here's the interface

```
export type Zone = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  box: {
    min: Point3d;
    max: Point3d;
  };
};

export type Point3d = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
};
```

This interface is used in an atom like this

```
effects: [
    syncEffect({
      refine: selectedZoneChecker,
    }),
  ]})
```

I'm trying to create a refine function for this atom. Here's the code

```
const minMaxChecker = object({
  x: number(),
  y: number(),
  z: number(),
});

const boxChecker = object({
  min: minMaxChecker,
  max: minMaxChecker,
});

const simpleZoneChecker = writableObject({
  id: string(),
  name: string(),
  box: boxChecker,
});
export const selectedZoneChecker = nullable<Zone>(simpleZoneChecker);
```

The problem is that the nullable checker returns a `Checker<T | undefined | null>`, but the atom only accepts a `Checker<T | null>`. I have tried using the voidable checker as well, but it returns a `Checker<T | undefined>`.

I am unable to change the type of the atom as it is used in multiple places throughout my application. I have searched through the documentation for a checker that would return a `Checker<T | null>` without undefined, but have been unable to find one.

Is there a way to resolve this issue without changing the type of the atom?

Tried reading through the docs multiple times and experimenting with different combinations of checkers

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `refine: or(simpleZoneChecker, literal(null))`